# Как в числе double избавиться от точки си

Tags: c

Нужно преобразовывать число типа double в инт, для начала пытаюсь его домножить, чтобы избавиться от точки. Например 3.14 должно стать 314. Код работает корректно не для всех чисел. На 3.14 все работает правильно, но если ввести, допустим 5.2356, то программа выдает 45235599999999981749174009856.000000. Есть ли какой-нибудь альтернативный способ?

```
int main()
{
    double num;
    scanf("%lf", &num);
    while (fmod(num,10)!=0){
        num=num*10;
    }
    num = num/10;
    printf("%lf", num);
}
```

Comment: Не храните значения критические к округлению дробной часи (например, деньги) в переменной с плавающей точкой. Число 5.2356 - не представимо в double точно.  Храните  в int умноженное число., например, число копеек вместо числа рублей.

Comment: у меня в задании нужно обязательно число в double передавать, а потом с ним работать

Comment: Тогда сравнивайте остаток от деления, с погрешностью представления числа, с некоторым запасам, поскольку в `num=num*10`, тоже происходит потеря точности.

Comment: Какова **реальная** задача?

Comment: число double преобразовать в строку вида пример 3.14=314/100

Comment: Вам нужна дробь? С любым знаменателем? `3.14 = 157/50` годится?

Comment: нереалистичная задача. тип **double** имеет двоичную систему исчисления, и она несовместима с десятичной. например десятичное число **0.1** при переносе в двоичную систему будет **0.000110011...** бесконечной

Comment: Возможно, это нужно сделать с помощью строковых операций, без преобразования в double?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, двоичную дробь можно отобразить в десятичную точно, так как `10 = 2 * 5`.

Comment: а задача была обратной, сначала десятичную запись записать в тип **double**, а потом вывести на экран как дробь. @Stanislav Volodarskiy А десятичная запись *может* поместиться в бинарный тип **точно** только при завершающей цифре **5**.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, вы правы. Я думал только про вторую часть задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том что десятичные дроби не отображаются точно в машинные вещественные числа. Чтобы решить задачу надо отказаться от использования `float`/`double`.

Программа читает число в виде строки, подсчитывает число цифр после десятичной точки, убирает десятичную точку, печатает десятичную дробь.

Два момента: [memmove](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/) чтобы подвинуть хвост строки на символ влево и нотация `%.*d` с аргументами `zeros, 0` в [printf](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) чтобы напечатать нужное число нулей:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char s[100];
    if (scanf("%99s", s) != 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    int zeros = 0;
    char *p = strchr(s, '.');
    if (p != NULL) {
        zeros = strlen(p) - 1;
        memmove(p, p + 1, zeros + 1);
    }
    printf("%s/1%.*d\n", s, zeros, 0);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror as_fraction.c 
>
> $ echo 3.14 | ./a.out
> 314/100
>
> $ echo 5.2356 | ./a.out
> 52356/10000
>
> $ echo 314 | ./a.out
> 314/1
> ```